# Can't rename folder (PHP + Linux)

Tags: php, linux, rename, move

I have next weird problem:

I create subfolder in Linux tmp folder with the help of PHP

```
mkdir(sys_get_temp_dir().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'subfolder');
```

Then I try to move this folder with help of PHP rename() func. I try to do it like this:

```
rename('/tmp/subfolder', '/other/folder/name');
```

But it returns me weird warning:

**Warning: rename(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory**

Is it something to do with access rights for these folders? Any ideas?

Comment: ...have you read the error message?

Comment: Error? There is no error, there is a warning. It says about copy() func, but I use rename() func (which, of course, can call copy() func itself). PHP manual says: rename — Renames a file or directory. So, rename() can rename folders.

Comment: @fcunited have You tried with backslash at the end of directory path i.e."rename('/tmp/subfolder/', '/other/folder/name/');" Check if exec("mv $oldname $newname"); forks for You, and remember that parent directories must be writable by Your php user

Comment: Yes. I tried with slash at the end.

Comment: exec("mv $src $dst"); works fine!!

Answer (score 4):

Is your `/tmp` on a different filesystem from your `/other`? This would be good practice if you wanted to separate your temporary file storage, which could fill up with rubbish, from e.g. `/var` (which could fill up with logs!)

If that's the case, then PHP has a core bug that prevents `rename()` from working reliably across filesystems:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54097

The workaround quoted there is to use `exec("mv "...)` but more robustly you can do:

```
if (@rename($from, $to)) {
    return;
}
exec("mv " . escapeshellarg($from) . " " . escapeshellarg($to));
```

If you encapsulate this in a function or method then you can call it in place of bare `rename()` whenever you need it.